# How do I increase the physical space for WSL2

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I increase the physical size of a WSL virtual disk? I only managed to increase the virtual size..

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space#how-to-expand-the-size-of-your-wsl-2-virtual-hard-disk) to manually increase the disk size (rather than relying on automatic resizing), then use `resize2fs` in your WSL (as you would on any other Linux) to make sure Linux is "aware" of the increased space.

Also, [here's an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4373) pushing for making it easier, from the outset.

Comment: Good find! I believe those are fairly recent MS additions to the docs, which is great.